# Python json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm writing a simple program that acts as a login screen. As part of it, I'm having the user create an account that will hold their name, age, city and login info in a JSON document. I've been able to write to the JSON easy enough, however whenever I read from the file it throws the 'Extra Data Error' and says it's on line 2 column 14

I'm using python 3.8.2, if that helps

This is the code in `main.py`

```
import json

def read(accList):
    with open('acc.json') as accountFile:
        first = accountFile.read(1)
        if not first:
            print("No accounts")
        else:
            accList["account"]=json.load(accountFile)
    accountFile.close()
    return(accList)

def write(accList):
    with open('acc.json',"w") as accountFile:
        accountFile.write(json.dumps(accList, indent = 4, sort_keys=True))
    accountFile.close()

def login(accList):
    accList=read(accList)
    user=input("Please enter your username: ")
    password=input("Please enter your password: ")

def create(accList):
    accList=read(accList)
    name=input("Please enter your name: ")
    age =input("How old are you: ")
    city = input("What city do you live in: ")
    user=input("Please create a username: ")
    password=input("Please create a  password: ")
    accList["account"].append({
        "name": name,
        "age": age,
        "city": city,
        "username": user,
        "password": password
    })
    write(accList)

def main():
    accList = {}
    accList["account"] = []
    returning=input("Welcome to Cael's login screen.\nDo you already have an account? ")
    if(returning.lower()=="yes"):
        login(accList)
    elif(returning.lower()=="no"):
        create(accList)
    #else:
     #   print("Sorry that's not a valid answer. Please only type \'Yes\' or \'No\'.")
main()
```

And here's the output that I have in the JSON (NOTE: It works fine adding one account but throws the error after that)

```
{
    "account": [
        {
            "age": "52",
            "city": "Jerome",
            "name": "Maynard",
            "password": "pass",
            "username": "mjkeenan"
        }
    ]
}
```

Sorry if this seems like a bit of a stupid question, or if there's an obvious mistake. I'm still new to JSON files as a whole

Comment: Looks like `accountFile.read(1)` read first symbol from file and after that `json.load` doesn’t get this symbol. Try to remove `accountFile.read(1)` and check result.

Comment: @AlexanderUshakov's suggestion is almost certainly the issue. What's happening is you've consumed the opening brace with the `read(1)` call. The decoder sees the string `"account"` as the entirety of the JSON object (a bare string is valid JSON), and then sees the colon following as "extra data".

Comment: It looks like you're using the read to determine if the file is empty? A more Pythonic approach would be to simply try to decode the file as JSON, and if it fails, then assume there are no accounts? Or perhaps when there are no accounts the file should still be valid JSON but have an empty array under the `accounts` key?

Comment: A third approach would be to put `accountFile.seek(0)` right after the read line. It will move the file pointer back to the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is because once you read a file the pointer will be at the end, so that is the reason why that error occurs, and after debugging that an another error has been thrown that dict object does not have append method and i just debugged it

```
import json

def read(accList):
    with open('acc.json') as accountFile:
        first = accountFile.read(1)
        # This will make the pointer to point at the beggining of the file
        accountFile.seek(0)

        if not first:
            print("No accounts")
        else:
            # this is to access only the account list and not the whole dictionary
            accList["account"]=json.load(accountFile)["account"]
    accountFile.close()
    return(accList)

def write(accList):
    with open('acc.json',"w") as accountFile:
        accountFile.write(json.dumps(accList, indent = 4, sort_keys=True))
    accountFile.close()

def login(accList):
    accList=read(accList)
    user=input("Please enter your username: ")
    password=input("Please enter your password: ")

def create(accList):
    accList=read(accList)
    name=input("Please enter your name: ")
    age =input("How old are you: ")
    city = input("What city do you live in: ")
    user=input("Please create a username: ")
    password=input("Please create a  password: ")
    accList["account"].append({
        "name": name,
        "age": age,
        "city": city,
        "username": user,
        "password": password
    })
    write(accList)

def main():
    accList = {}
    accList["account"] = []
    returning=input("Welcome to Cael's login screen.\nDo you already have an account? ")
    if(returning.lower()=="yes"):
        login(accList)
    elif(returning.lower()=="no"):
        create(accList)
    #else:
     #   print("Sorry that's not a valid answer. Please only type \'Yes\' or \'No\'.")
main()
```